# 'temporary' USD prices in the Price Database

Tags: gnucash

I've been exploring my GnuCash data and noticed something I can't explain. In the Price Database, under Currencies->USD, I have 18 entries for a *currency* named after the fund VFIAX. All 18 have the same date (6/29/2022) and that date matches a transaction from one account where I hold that fund. The *source* columns is "temporary" and the *type* is "transaction".

What's strange is that the price for all 18 entries is 1000000/352760417, or 0.00283478517375718. That's not correct for the price of USD. The reason I noticed this is because some SQL I've written is pulling these prices and incorrectly calculating the value of my VFIAX holdings.

Are these safe to delete? Any idea how they got created in the first place? And why would a FUND create a price within currency/USD? I couldn't find answers in the mailing list archive or GC documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an error was made when the transaction was entered, the currency transfer wizard kicked in with bad input data, and these bad output entries were created as a result.  (That's just my guess from 2nd hand information.)  In any case, Price Database entries are not critical to the operation of the software, and can be deleted at whim.  I checked my Price Database and see several "Source: Temporary" lines in there, so that's normal.  To remove the bad entries, you can shift-select the lines in the Price Database window, and click the "Remove" button on the right side of the dialogue.

Comment: OK, thanks. I don't remember the specifics but it's possible I made a mistake when entering the transaction. I'll accept this answer since you've confirmed it's safe to delete the prices.